# Cisco ASR 1001 transceivers not working

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-asr, transceiver

I've a Cisco ASR 1001 v03.
When it got to my hands it wouldn't save the config after reboots, after some research I found out the config-register had a wrong value and it was fixed by running following command: config-register 0x2001

Now it saves the config I'm trying to give it access to the internet, and I realized that there's some issue with the "HP 1G SFP RJ-45 Module" transceivers.
When connecting them I get the following error:

```
TRANSCEIVER-6-INSERTED: SIP0/0: transceiver module inserted in GigabitEthernet0/0/0
TRANSCEIVER-3-INIT_FAILURE: SIP0/0: Detected for transceiver module in GigabitEthernet0/0/0, module disabled
```

Any idea how to make it enable them?

Considering it might be a bug, thought about upgrading the IOS asr1001-universal.03.12.01.S.154-2.S1-std.bin, and I got asr1001-universalk9.03.16.06.S.155-3.S6-ext.bin, but I'm a bit concerned about the k9 and the std/ext, and wether they're fully compatible.

Please kindly help me make this router work again. Thank you

Comment: Please add the exact type of transceivers to your question.

Comment: @Zac67 thanks for the quick reply, I'll add asap and reply :)

Comment: @Zac67 they are "HP 1G SFP RJ-45 Module"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router is rejecting an unsupported, third-party module.

Not sure about an ASR 1001 but to make Cisco devices accept third-party SFP modules you can try:

1. remove rejected module
2. `switch#configure terminal`
3. `switch(config)# service unsupported-transceiver`
4. `switch(config)# no errdisable detect cause gbic-invalid`
5. reinsert module

Note that there's no support for these modules and Cisco TAC may require you to replace them with a supported type when you open a case with them. Since the ASR 1001 is end of life anyway that shouldn't matter to you.

Comment: Not sure what happened but one day I managed to connect them and they were properly recognized, so now they're working.

Comment: Your 4th step didn't work for me as it said unrecognized command

Comment: Your mileage may vary - See "not sure about an ASR 1001" above. Glad to hear it worked (possibly with just `service unsupported-transceiver`).